# what's the differences between ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer() and ReactDOM.createPortal() methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I didn't find any documentation about `ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer()` method.

It seems they are doing the same thing. But I wonder is the following code equivalent?

```js
if(ReactDOM.createPortal) {
  ReactDOM.createPortal(children, container)
} else {
  ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer(this, children, container);
}
```